# EasyUI Filter and serverside pagination jquery Conflict

Tags: datagrid, pagination, jquery-easyui, jquery-pagination, jquery-filter

I am using **EasyUI along with Liferay MVC portlet**. I have applied **serverside pagination and DataGrid filter on same datagrid**. Without filter DataGrid pagination is working fine. But when I apply filter, no data is displayed on pagination's next page. After a lots of effort I found that in DataGrid filter plugin's JS (**datagrid-filter.js**) they have done this code for pagination:

```
if (opts.pagination){
    var dg = $(this);
    var pager = dg[name]('getPager');
    pager.pagination({
        onSelectPage:function(pageNum, pageSize){
            opts.pageNumber = pageNum;
            opts.pageSize = pageSize;
            pager.pagination('refresh',{
                pageNumber:pageNum,
                pageSize:pageSize
            });

            //dg.datagrid('loadData', state.filterSource);
            dg[name]('loadData', state.filterSource);
        },
        onBeforeRefresh:function(){
            //dg('reload');
            dg[name]('reload');
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (name == 'datagrid'){
        var start = (opts.pageNumber-1)*parseInt(opts.pageSize);
        var end = start + parseInt(opts.pageSize);
        data.rows = data.rows.slice(start, end);
    } else {
        var topRows = [];
        var childRows = [];
        $.map(data.rows, function(row){
            row._parentId ? childRows.push(row) : topRows.push(row);
        });
        data.total = topRows.length;
        var start = (opts.pageNumber-1)*parseInt(opts.pageSize);  
        var end = start + parseInt(opts.pageSize);  
        data.rows = $.extend(true,[],topRows.slice(start, end).concat(childRows));
    }
}
```

Now if I comment this line:

```
dg[name]('loadData', state.filterSource);
```

then pagination works properly but then filter doesn't respond anything. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you should follow these steps:

1. Make sure that `remoteFilter`is `false` (default is false);
2. Don't use **limit** and **offset** in your sql query

**Understanding**

In the normal paging, when clicking on next or previous, the EasyUi sends parameters with limit and offset to server limiting the results by page. When using **filter**, if `remoteFilter` is `false`, then the pagination table occurs locally. Thus you don't need to use limit and offset to fetch all results.

**Example**

```
$('#table').datagrid({
      your code here....
  }).datagrid('enableFilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

Set clientPaging to false

```js
pagination: true,
remoteFilter: true,
clientPaging: false
```

check http://www.jeasyui.com/extension/datagrid_filter.php

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).